# Is $("div p") equivalent to $("div*p")?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The star operator seems to recurse all selected children, which is the same thing that happens with a space. I find it weird the space is like an operator but `$("div p")` does the same thing as `$("div*p")`.

Comment: nope. `$(" div p ")` and `$(" div*p ")` do not give same result(log both selectors in current page console).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not equivalent. The star operator means, that at least one element needs to be between them. An equivalent selector expression would be

```
p * div, p > div
```

matching both cases. [Selectors level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#descendant-combinators) will most likely introduce another operator

```
p >> div
```

that is indeed equivalent to `p<space>div`.

For the jQuery part: If you write `$('p div')` or any of the other selectors, you will make acquaintance with auto-closing elements in HTML. In this specific case: `div` elements cannot be inside `p` elements. The browser will close the `p` automatically, when it encounters the `div`. If you start with this:

```
<p>
    <div></div>
</p>
```

your DOM will look like this:

```
<p></p>
<div></div>
<p></p>
```

hence never matching any of `p div`, `p * div`, ... See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oke23ku0/) (attention: will twice do an `alert()`).

*Edit:* As @Bharadwaj points out in the comments, the notation of `p*div` is an error and will never match. The reason is, that `*` is a [placeholder for an element name](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#universal-selector) and thus must be surrounded by whitespace.

Comment: Using `*` in `jQuery` nothing is selected for me!

Comment: Do you happen to have example code for that? A JSFiddle or so?

Comment: I wasn't used nested `div p`, so I got 0

Comment: `$('div * p')` will select nested but `$('div*p')` (as in question) selects none even there are some items present!

Comment: That's not true. Space is ignored in CSS with the sole exception of two adjacent selectors (like `div<space>p`). `div * p` and `div*p` are completely identical. Everything else would be a [bug in jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues).

Comment: I tried in fiddle, local machine and in w3schools editor also, `$('div*p')` selects none and `$('div * p')` selects nested elements. http://jsfiddle.net/4yqp63jv/

Comment: This explanation makes sense, and was indeed what I was going to say if asked as well, but it turns out that's not what happens in practice: check `console.log(document.querySelectorAll("div p").length, $("div > p").length, $("div * p").length)`. If this answer were true then for the three numbers A B C the condition A = B + C should hold, but in fact it's A = C.

Comment: Also, it's not a bug in jQuery: substituting `document.querySelectorAll` for `$` gives the same results.

Comment: I must apologize to @Bharadwaj! Yes, it's true, those are not the same. The reason: `*` is a _substitute_ for an element name, hence needs to stand alone. I'll update the answer. Again, I'm sorry for this!

Comment: More precisely, `*` is a simple selector, just like an element selector; whitespace as a descendant selector is a combinator, similar to `>` and `+`. Whitespace can only be omitted between a simple selector and a combinator - not two simple selectors, if they represent separate elements. You can do `div>*>p` which will match p grandchildren of div - the `>` combinator is used in place of a descendant combinator.

Answer (score 4):

In this HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <div>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`div p` selects both paragraphs, it means a `p` element anywhere inside a `div`.
`div * p` only the nested one, because `*` stands for any element (so a `p` inside any element inside a `div`)

http://jsfiddle.net/21ru2x5c/

BTW `p div` shouldn't match anything, because you can't have a block-level element inside a paragraph. The browser closes a `<p>` element before opening a block level element while parsing the DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/21ru2x5c/1/

Comment: OP asked in `jQuery`, I tried in `jQuery` by alerting `.length` and I got `0` if I use `*`!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/21ru2x5c/2/ logs `2` for `div p` and `1` for `div * p`. If you try with the second form where divs are inside `p` it correctly logs `0` for both cases: http://jsfiddle.net/21ru2x5c/3/

Comment: Ok, I haven't used nested in my example ;)

Comment: As in question `$(div*p).length` give `0` but, `$(div * p).length` give `1`.

Comment: @Bharadwaj the space isn't optional, otherwise there wouldn't be a difference between `div *.foo` and `div * .foo`. Or, to put it another way, substitute the `*` with any other selector, for example `div div p` makes sense, but `divdivp` doesn't.